# Azure Powershell Scripting parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

Good Day

I have been tasked to gather a list of all the VMs in our different subscriptions, and I have a script that gathers: Mode, Name, ResourceGroupName, location, VMSize, and Status. There are two empty columns: subscription and availability set.

A bit of a backstory, the company I am contracted to hired a vendor to deploy the resources and now they don't know if the vendor did what they were suppose to.

What I am trying to figure out:

1. How to list the ASG the resource is in
2. The NSG the resource is in
3. The vCPUs and RAM
4. Storage account

I have been scouring google to find the PSObjects I need to define. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have written a PowerShell script to generate an Azure Inventory, let me know if it helps - 
https://manjunathrao.com/2016/12/30/powershell-generate-azure-inventory/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.How to list the ASG the resource is in

If you want to list all the ASGs in the VM, you need to list them via all the NICs, you could refer to the command below, the `$asgnames` is the list of all ASGs, **note** if different NICs have the same ASG, it will output several times.

```
$nics = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "<VM Name>").NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
$nicnames = @()
$asgnames = @()
foreach($nic in $nics){
    $a = $nic.Id -split"/"
    $nicname = $a[8]
    $nicnames += $nicname
    $ipconfig = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipConfigurations -ResourceName "$nicname/ipconfig1" -ApiVersion 2018-07-01
    $asgids = $ipconfig.Properties.applicationSecurityGroups.id 

    foreach ($asgid in $asgids){
        $a = $asgid -split"/"
        $asganme = $a[8]
        $asgnames += $asganme
    }
}
```

[image]

> 2.The NSG the resource is in

If you want to get NSGs in the VM, you need to get them via all NICs and VNET Subnet.

Get the NSG of the NIC, the `$nsgnic` is the NSG:

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces -ResourceName "<NIC name>" -ApiVersion 2018-07-01
$a = $nic.properties.networkSecurityGroup.id -split"/"
$nsgnic = $a[8]
```

Get the NSG of subnet, the `$nsgsub` is the NSG:

```
$subnet = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets -ResourceName "<Vnet name>/<Subnet name>" -ApiVersion 2018-07-01
$b = $subnet.properties.networkSecurityGroup.id -split"/"
$nsgsub = $a[8]
```

Then the **NSG**s of the VM will be the `sum` of `$nsgnic` and `$nsgsub`.

> 3.The vCPUs and RAM

Try the command below, `NumberOfCores` is the **`vCPUs`** , `MemoryInMB` is the **`RAM`**, **note** the RAM in result is in `MB`, you could convert it to `GB` if necessary.

```
Get-AzureRmVMSize -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -VMName "<VMName>"
```

[image]

> 4.Storage account

If I do not misunderstand, the storage account here you mean the `Diagnostics storage account`, try the command below, `$storage` is the storage account uri.

```
$a = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -ResourceName "<VM Name>" -ApiVersion 2018-06-01
$storage = $a.properties.diagnosticsProfile.bootDiagnostics.storageUri
```

[image]

Comment: Joy, thank you for this. I notice in your retrieval of the ASGs you are picking individual machines. I am assuming that i can create a for loop to run this command through all 178 resources that we have in our azure account. 

For the NSGs we did assign them on the subnet, so I think I am able to get it that way.

The last two make perfect sense. Thanks again!